# Number of distinct ways of writing elements in HK as hk.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I am aware that this question has already been asked, however I am trying to figure out how the result follows from a particular proof given in Dummit and Foote. Specifically, I want to show that if $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$, then the number of distinct ways of writing each element of $HK$ in the form $hk$ for some $h\in H$ and $k\in K$ is $|H\cap K|$.

The text says the result follows from the proof of the following proposition: If $H$ and $K$ are finite subgroups, then $|HK|=|H\cap K|$. The proof of this goes as follows. We can write $HK=\bigcup_{h\in H}hK$. Since each coset of $K$ has $|K|$ elements in it, it suffices to find the number of distinct left cosets ofthe form $hK$ where $h\in H$. We have $h_1K=h_2K$ iff $h_2^{-1}h_1\in H\cap K$ iff $h_1(H\cap K)=h_2(H\cap K)$. And the number of distinct cosets $h(H\cap K)$ for $h\in H$ is $|H|/|H\cap K|$. So $HK$ consists of $|H|/|H\cap K|$ distinct cosets of $K$, which gives the result.

But how does the proof of this result imply that the number of distinct ways of writing elements of $HK$ in the form $hk$ is $|H\cap K|$?
I know that if we assume $h_1k_1=h_2k_2$, then $h_2^{-1}h_1=k_2k_1^{-1}\in H\cap K$ and so $h_1(H\cap K)=h_2(H\cap K)$ and $k_1(H\cap K)=k_2(H\cap K)$ but not sure if this helps.

Comment: Second paragraph second line I think it should be $$|HK||H\cap K|=|H||K|$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix $g=hk$. Given any solution $(h_1,k_1)$ to $h_1k_1 = g$, you can associate to it $h_1^{-1}h = k_1k^{-1}\in H\cap K$.

That is you have a map $\{(h_1,k_1)\in H\times K\mid h_1k_1= g\}\to H\cap K$ defined by $(h_1,k_1)\mapsto h_1^{-1}h$ (or also $k_1k^{-1}$)

Conversely, given $l\in H\cap K$, you may define $(h_1,k_1)$ as $h_1= hl^{-1}, k_1 = lk$ and then clearly $h_1k_1= g, h_1\in H, k_1\in K$.

Now if you compose these two operations in a row, you clearly see that they give the identity, no matter the order : therefore they're an inverse pair of bijections, which shows that the two sets have the same size : $|H\cap K|$.

Comment: Thanks, but at what point was the proof of the statement in the second paragraph used?

Comment: Well I think it's just a fancier way to say what I've said. The thing is that the proof in the second paragraph shows that $h_1K= h_2K$ if and only if $h_1(H\cap K) = h_2(H\cap K)$. Then it's hidden in the sentence "it suffices to find the number of distinct left cosets of the form hK " : if you explicit what this means in terms of $HK$, you'll see how "number of ways to write $hk$" relates to "number of cosets of the form hK"

Comment: Thanks for this post. I also want to mention that, without checking that the two operations are identity, we can check directly that the map $(h_1,k_1) \mapsto h_1^{-1}h = k_1k^{-1}$ is an injection. Since the map was shown to be a surjection, we have that the map is a bijection.